# Jar library is not recognized inside Intelij IDEA

Tags: import, jar, reflections

Hi! I am new to intelij IDEA, and I cannot get [google reflection library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to work inside intelijIDEA.
I've tried adding it as recommender in many sites, by going to the module configuration, then dependency, clicking on the add library icon and giving the jar file.
It gets recognised in the editer (not underlined with red), but when I try running the problem it throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate`
so I am guessing that the import did not work.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to add the guava library as well, and probably other libraries.

I would search for it using [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/), and than download the appropriate binary and add it as library.

If you're not using maven already, try it, it would save you a lot of time. otherwise, look at the [pom.xml](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/source/browse/trunk/reflections/pom.xml) of the Reflections library, and decide which other libraries you might need at runtime.